# Split Mysql Location entry into 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split, location

Is there an easy way to take a table column for 'location' in the format latitude,longitude and split it into a column for latitude and a column for longitude?

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`location`, ',', 1) AS latitude,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`location`, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS longitude
FROM users_profiles;
```

this code will display the latitude and longitude columns as I want them, but I'm unable to insert that back into the respective latitude/longitude columns I've created in the users_profiles table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the query doesn't set the columns.  To create the columns do:

```
alter table users_profiles add column latitude decimal(10, 4);
alter table users_profiles add column longitude decimal(10, 4);
```

To assign them use `update`:

```
update users_profiles
    set latitude = cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`location`, ',', 1) as decimal(10, 4)),
        longitude = cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ',', -1) as decimal(10, 4));
```

The `cast()` operations are, strictly speaking, unnecessary.  I like to be explicit about casts between strings and other types, in case something unusual happens in code.  It can be hard to spot problems with implicit casts.

Comment: You don't need to call `CAST` explicitly. The assignment will automatically perform the conversion.

Comment: He said he created the columns, why do you think he hasn't?

Comment: That's correct Barmar, I manually created the columns in the user_profiles table for latitude and longitude with the intentions of deleting the location column once the data was copied over. I can "select" the data parsed as I expect it to look, I just wasn't sure how I can format the sql query to take those results and place them into the table.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this did exactly what I was looking for. I removed the alter table lines as I already manually created them, no big deal. I can't accept an answer within 5 minutes apparently, but I will when I can.